# Modulo TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, concatenation, typeerror, modulo

When trying to use the modulo to insert text, it gives me

TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

in the story() function

```
from random import *
f = open('madlib.txt', 'a')
head = ["You are a %s %s. You %s out of your %s to the sound of %s %s.", "You see a %s %s down the street. You %s to go catch it, but you trip on a %s. You hear %s %s is your ears."]
body = ["You make your way down the %s, and %s. You %s head first on to the %s. You %s and get back up.", "Unlike usual, you open your %s and get to work. You dont like to %s, so you %s. Your %s has no power over you! You reluctantly %s the urges and open it back up..."]
end = ["You get on your %s and %s. You need to %s your %s %s. You press the submit %s, and hope it gets in on time!", "You open your %s and %s. You casually %s for %s. You wonder why this %s is so random! You close your %s and go to sleep."]
top = ""
middle = "" 
bottom = ""
top_list = []
middle_list = []
end_list = []
def selector():
    num = randint(1,2)
    if num == 1:
        top = head[1]
    elif num == 2:
        top = head[0]
    num = randint(1,2)
    if num == 1:
        middle = body[1]
    elif num == 2:
        middle = body[0]
    num = randint(1,2)
    if num == 1:
        bottom = end[1]
    elif num == 2:
        bottom = end[0]
def runner():
    top_list.append(str(input("adjective")))
    top_list.append(str(input("noun")))
    top_list.append(str(input("verb")))
    top_list.append(str(input("noun")))
    top_list.append(str(input("verb -ing")))
    top_list.append(str(input("plural noun")))
    top_list.append(str(input("plural noun")))
    middle_list.append(str(input("noun")))
    middle_list.append(str(input("verb")))
    middle_list.append(str(input("verb")))
    middle_list.append(str(input("noun")))
    middle_list.append(str(input("verb")))
    end_list.append(str(input("noun")))
    end_list.append(str(input("verb")))
    end_list.append(str(input("verb")))
    end_list.append(str(input("school subject")))
    end_list.append(str(input("noun")))
    end_list.append(str(input("noun")))
def story():
    tuple(top_list)
    tuple(middle_list)
    tuple(end_list)
    f.write(top % tuple(top_list))
    print(top % tuple(top_list))
    f.write(middle % tuple(middle_list))
    print(middle % tuple(middle_list))
    f.write(end % tuple(end_list))
    print(end % tuple(end_list))
selector()
runner()
story()
```

I looked at all the other Stack overflow questions having to do with this Type error, but none of them actually address the same problem.

Comment: `top` and `middle` are empty strings. How do you expect that to do any formatting?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Look below, they are assigned later

Comment: No, they are not. `selector()` doesn't do anything.

Comment: If you don't believe me, try printing each string without any attempt at formatting.

Comment: It picks a random number and then assigns top, middle, and end a value provided above. How would it not do anything?

Comment: They're all local variables that get thrown away. Again, if you don't believe me, you can do some printing to see what you have.

Comment: It isn't that I don't believe you, more I don't understand what is wrong

Comment: You should read up on scopes, particularly function and global scopes.

Comment: Also, if `top` and `middle` did get saved with new values, they would each be a single character, which wouldn't work any better. Additionally, are you sure you want to format `top` and `middle` rather than `head` and `body`?

Comment: `head` and `body` are lists though

Comment: Sorry; the strings they contain, then. You're already trying to do it with `end`, anyway. They're the only strings I see in your program that can be formatted (i.e., they contain formatting syntax).

Answer (score 1):

there are 3 problems with your code, the first one is the function `selector` in this one you don't save the the change in the externals variables as you may think, but in a internal to the function, because when you do `top=head[0]` what python do is create a new variable called top in the namespace of the function and leave alone the external one, to fix this you have several options, like return those values and assign then to the corresponding variables or telling the function that you want to use the external one using the command `global` like this:

```
def selector():
    global top,middle,bottom
    top    = head[ randint(0,1) ]
    middle = body[ randint(0,1) ]
    bottom = end[ randint(0,1) ]
```

also there is no need to all those ifs, because randind can give you the index directly as show above.

The second problem is in the function `runner`, here you fill your top_list with 7 items instead of 6 as you defined your top text with 6 `%s`

And finally in `story` you're using the `end` list instead of the `bottom` string, also you're doing redundant stuff here, the 3 first lines of that function accomplish nothing because you don't save the result, and all the other call to tuple is doing the same job over and over again, to eliminate the redundancy do this

```
def story():
    top_text    = tuple(top_list)
    middle_text = tuple(middle_list)
    end_text    = tuple(end_list)
    f.write(top % top_text)
    print(top % top_text)
    f.write(middle % middle_text)
    print(middle % middle_text)
    f.write(bottom % end_text)  #is bottom, no end
    print(bottom % end_text)    #is bottom, no end
```

Answer (score 0):

You're providing a list, not a tuple, try instead:
`f.write(top % tuple(top_list))`

Comment: I made them tuples at the beginning of the function

Comment: You're not assigning them when you call tuple, if you want to do that do `top_list = tuple(top_list)`

Comment: I did what you said in my program and it called the same error

Comment: This would eventually be a problem, but the current issue is a different problem caused by a different error message.